# Stack Overflow Teams is not working

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Today I tried to create a free account in Stack Overflow Teams, but after inputting the name and the link, it showed that it was unavailable. Are there any issues in Teams or am I doing something wrong?!

Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: They have run out of databases ...

Comment: huh, the marketing campaign turned out to be too effective :) Does the issue persist?

Comment: @rene only if we used databases

Comment: @Taryn heh, NoSQL for you then  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for your report; this issue has been fixed.

Due to the overwhelming success of Free teams (!), we started seeing some DB deadlocks and had to update the infrastructure code that pre-provisioned database schemas for each new team. The deadlocks are now gone, but a bug in the new provisioning code caused some team links to be set incorrectly. The mismatch resulted in unique link validation failures in some cases when the name and link of a team did not match. The validation logic has been fixed, and new teams should no longer be affected.

Comment: A good stress test?